# How reliable is the format of demangled names?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, demangler

I am working on a pretty [dynamic C++ program](https://github.com/LDMX-Software/fire) which allows the user to define their own data structures which are then serialized in an output [HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/) data file. Instead of requiring the user to define a new HDF5 data type, I am "splitting" their data structures into HDF5 subgroups in which I store the different member variable data sets. I am interested in labeling the HDF5 group that has the subgroup members with the type of the data structure that was written to it so that future users of the data file will have more knowledge about how to use the data contained within it.

All of this context gets me to my question in the title. **How reliable are demangled names?** The crux of the issue could be summarized with the following example (using `boost` to demangle as an example, not a necessity). If I use

```
std::string tn = boost::core::demangle(typeid(MyType).name());
```

to get the demangled name of `MyType` on one system with a given compiler, will I get the same result if I use the same code on a different system with a potentially different compiler? Could I safely do `tn_sys_with_clang == tn_sys_with_gcc` and trust that this equality holds as long as `MyType` is the same type?

The answer seems to me to be obviously yes, and I have checked a few examples across many different compilers on Compiler Explorer; however, I want to be confident that I am not missing any edge cases. Moreover, I'm not sure how the demangling process differs between compilers and how that might lead to the introduction of differing amounts of whitespace.

The emphasis here is that the only variable changing is the system and compiler. I know that changing the definition of `MyType` or moving it to a different namespace or including a pesky `using` directive or changing how I demangle could change the string output by the demangling. I want to focus on a more limited question where only the compiler and system change.

Comment: I'll bet there's some documentation for `boost::core::demangle` that would be a good starting point.

Comment: Not sure of boost.demangle accounts for that, but I think MSVC likes to insert `struct`/`class`/`union`/`enum` into the type names. Might want to check for that.

Comment: Microsoft also mangles `struct X` differently from `class X`.  Other C++ compilers consider those to be the same.

Comment: @PeteBecker is there more available outside of the [official Boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html)? The page doesn't do much except explain how it works.

Comment: Actually you might want to check documentation for `abi::__cxa_demangle`, since all `boost` does is call that library.

Comment: Uhm, it works the other way round. There is documentation and standards how to mangle names. If the compiler with such and such options follows such and such standard to mangle, you get the same demangled name... https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unreliable.

If you compile *with the same compiler* on the *same OS* then you should have some stability — but that is absolutely ***not*** guaranteed. ABI changes in name mangling can happen at any time in a compiler’s release cycle.

<sup>Individual compiler teams *may* have some information about this in their documentation. I am not going to look it up. Sorry.</sup>

All bets are off if you compile with *either* different compilers or different operating systems.

For example, LLVM/Clang on Windows comes with a version that uses MSVC as the backend. Consequently, name mangling on the native Windows Clang port is *not* compatible with the native Linux Clang.

Finally, just running a few tests with your (current) compiler is always a good way to shoot yourself in the foot. As the adage goes, “just because it works on your compiler, today...”

Answer (score 0):

The reliability of de-mangled names does not seem to be something that is well documented. For this reason, I am going to simply document the few tests that I've done on my x86_64 system allowing me to compare gcc and clang. These tests [done through Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/hMqPcKsTf) verifies that the returned strings for the same types are the same (including whitespace).

Maybe if I start using this in my application, one of the users will find an issue and I can update this question with another answer down the line, but for now, I think it is safe(ish) to trust de-mangling.